# Serialize vec of external crate enum which doesn't implement serialization

Tags: serialization, enums, rust, serde

I use external crate with enum which does not implement serialization, and I want to use it in struct which will contain Vec of of this enum and have possibility de/serialize this struct. Based on [serde documentation](https://serde.rs/remote-derive.html) I created below code

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum ExternalCrateColor {
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(remote = "ExternalCrateColor")]
enum LocalColor {
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Hue {
    #[serde(with = "LocalColor")]
    color: ExternalCrateColor
}

fn main() {
    let tones = Hue { color: ExternalCrateColor::Blue };
    let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&tones).unwrap();
    println!("serialized = {}", serialized);
    let deserialized: Hue = serde_json::from_str(&serialized).unwrap();
    if deserialized.color == ExternalCrateColor::Blue {
      println!("Blue tones");
    }
}
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6f6e73a7d673fbc9b789cd853d942a09)

But what I want is to have Hue struct to contain Vec of ExternalCrateColor:

```
struct Hue {
    #[serde(with = "LocalColor")]
    colors: Vec<ExternalCrateColor>
}
```

and it does not works because de/serialization expect in this case single ExternalCrateColor. How to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can make this work using the remote-type feature of serde, but you can do it by first defining a conversion:

```rust
fn to_local(color: &ExternalCrateColor) -> LocalColor {
    match color {
        ExternalCrateColor::Red => LocalColor::Red,
        ExternalCrateColor::Green => LocalColor::Green,
        ExternalCrateColor::Blue => LocalColor::Blue,
    }
}
fn to_external(color: &LocalColor) -> ExternalCrateColor {
    match color {
        LocalColor::Red => ExternalCrateColor::Red,
        LocalColor::Green => ExternalCrateColor::Green,
        LocalColor::Blue => ExternalCrateColor::Blue,
    }
}
```

Using these conversions, you can implement it like this:

```rust
fn color_vec_ser<S: Serializer>(
    vec: &Vec<ExternalCrateColor>,
    serializer: S
) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
    // First convert the vector into a Vec<LocalColor>.
    let vec2: Vec<LocalColor> = vec.iter().map(to_local).collect();

    // Instead of serializing Vec<ExternalCrateColor>, we serialize Vec<LocalColor>.
    vec2.serialize(serializer)
}
fn color_vec_deser<'de, D: Deserializer<'de>>(
    deserializer: D
) -> Result<Vec<ExternalCrateColor>, D::Error> {
    // Deserialize as if it was a Vec<LocalColor>.
    let vec: Vec<LocalColor> = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;

    // Convert it into an Vec<ExternalCrateColor>
    Ok(vec.iter().map(to_external).collect())
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Hue {
    #[serde(serialize_with = "color_vec_ser")]
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "color_vec_deser")]
    colors: Vec<ExternalCrateColor>
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alice this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

I will need to check the `serde`'s codebase, but I was able to make it work with a hack.

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq,)]
enum ExternalCrateColor {
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(remote = "ExternalCrateColor")]
enum LocalColor {
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Adapter {
    #[serde(with = "LocalColor")]
    color: ExternalCrateColor
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Hue {
    colors: Vec<Adapter>
}

fn main() {
        let adapters = vec![Adapter {  color: ExternalCrateColor::Blue }, Adapter {color: ExternalCrateColor::Green}];
        let hue = Hue {colors: adapters};
//     let tones = Hue { color: ExternalCrateColor::Blue };
//     let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&tones).unwrap();
//     println!("serialized = {}", serialized);
//     let deserialized: Hue = serde_json::from_str(&serialized).unwrap();
//     if deserialized.color == ExternalCrateColor::Blue {
//       println!("Blue tones");
//     }
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3f8eb6d3ce2e95078c391d7aa0c83ed9)

Comment: Thank you, that is very neat trick. I like how short it is with doing almost everything which I need. In this specific case I will follow second answer from @AliceRyhl because even being much more verbose on start, later in use in contex of whole program it's a bit more convininet to operates on the same type. Because users will sent json form of it I also prefer serialized form from Alices's answer  `{ colors: [Blue, Green] }` vs  `{"colors":[{"color":"Green"},{"color":"Blue"}]}`. That just my preference and I think your answer is very valuable.

Comment: Even I liked his answer better. but thanks for acknowledging :)